# Entry Auto Complete on Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a `Entry` Control on **Xamarin.forms**, I want to make this `Entry` to display auto complete values? Is that available on **Xamarin.Forms**?

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin Forms Labs (XLabs) has an AutoCompleteView, the XLabs package is not being maintained going forward, but you could use it as guidance to make your own.

https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/AutoCompleteView

Comment: I recommend you to add some code to explain more, stackoverflow doesn't like links because maybe will delete after awhile ..

Answer (score 2):

To do that I'm using the `SFAutoComplete` plugin, it have a lot of features to customize your autocomplete, you can see it here:

https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfautocomplete/overview

https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin/autocomplete